# How to get a JSON object's key from the object itself in JavaScript/a Vue v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, key

I'm not looking for the keys that this object contains but the key of the object itself (the key in the array containing the object).

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "Object name (text)": {
        "raw": "Some more text.",
    },
    "Another name": {
        "raw": "Some other text.",
    }
}
```

and would like to get *"Object name (text)"* for the first item.

My Vue code is:

```
<CustomComponent
    v-for="object in objects"
    :key="getKey(object)"
    :object="object"
/>
```

I'm not sure if the getKey-method approach is how one is intended to get unique identifiers for iterating through the JSON array. Its code currently is:

```
getKey(object) {
   return Object.keys(object)[0];
}
```

Now I'd like to somehow pass the name of the object to the CustomComponent ("Object name (text)" in the first case).

One temporary workaround that I intended to use until I find something more appropriate was getting the keys from the objects array like so:
`:objectName="getObjectName(object)"` and `itemNumber: -1` in data and this method:

```
getObjectName(object) {
   this.itemNumber = this.itemNumber + 1;
   var objectName = Object.keys(this.objects)[this.itemNumber];
   console.log("Object name: ", objectName);
}
```

However, the first line of this method causes it to run hundreds of times instead of only two times (why is that?; it works in the first 2 executions of the method and when commenting out that line) and I think this is unlikely the proper method to simply retrieve the object's name/key.

It also didn't work when putting the above code into the getKey method which would make more sense (and I had the code in that method before creating a separate method to debug). Then the key could be accessed in the component with `this.$vnode.key` However, it keeps being undefined. This might be a separate problem even though it could resolve this problem here as well - I might create a new question for it. It enters the methods "getKey" and "getObjectName" 6 times each even though it only renders two items on the page, like it should.

-> How to get the JSON object's key in JavaScript?
(Preferably from the object itself after iterating through a JSON array with a loop with Vue instead of only indirectly by checking the objects array.)

Edit: as a **workaround** I have now done this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(this.objects);
    keys.forEach(element => {
      this.objectsWithKeys.push({
        object: this.objects[element],
        key: element
      });
    });

<CustomComponent
   v-for="objectWithKeys in objectsWithKeys"
   :key="objectWithKeys.key"
   :object="objectWithKeys.object"
>
</CustomComponent>

this.$vnode.key
```

Comment: You can't rely on the order in which keys will be returned from a call to `Object.keys()`. There are rules for the ordering, but they're not under your control and they depend on the "life story" of every individual object. If you need to know the keys, keep an array whose order is completely under your control.

Comment: Good to know. If the .json file has the ordering as it should be but Object.keys() could ignore the order, how to transfer it to an array "whose order is completely under [my] control"? Should I try to convert the JSON object to a js array or what would you recommend?

Comment: The issue is that writing code that only works if property names appear in a certain order is just asking for bugs. It's hard to give advice without knowing *why* you want to get a property name. Where do the objects come from? How is it that your code doesn't know the property names?

Comment: Isn't the code only expecting the order of the objects variable to be the same as what Object.keys() returns? I wouldn't call that a certain order but simply the objective order of the .json file which I thought Object.keys() would use. If this is not the case is there a way to make Object.keys() use this order? And if not: would you recommend creating some sort of 2nd array for mapping the correct order? I want to get the prop name because it's text that I want to display in the component & currently it's contained like so in the .json file. How is it that I can't get the JSON object's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, I used `var objectsWithKeys = data[Object.keys(data)];` and `{{ $vnode.key }}`.